# Shelah's materialize vs. realize;note: tags are badly chosen due to the lack of them

Tags: model-theory, forcing

Can someone please explain to me in some detail the exact difference between *materialize* and *realize* for a Galois type $p$? Esp. is realize a special case for materialize? Why is it so? What is the difference between $gtp(a,M,N)$ and $tp(a,M,N)$? The relevant definitions are [here](http://shelah.logic.at/files/88r.pdf). Search for the keywords *materialize* and *gtp* in your browser.